# c# MongoDB camelCased field name while using filters

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a model class which is immutable and mapped to mongo through BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap. If I understand correctly, when I want to store properties into database with camelCased names convention pack won't work so I have to use SetElementName method to set it manually as following.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Document>(cm =>
  {
    cm.MapIdMember(d => d.Id).SetElementName("id");
    cm.MapProperty(d => d.SchemaId).SetElementName("schemaId");
    cm.MapProperty(d => d.Filename).SetElementName("filename");
    cm.MapProperty(d => d.Content).SetElementName("content");
    cm.MapCreator(d => new Document(d.Id, d.SchemaId, d.Filename, d.Content));
  });
```

The problem is filtering. I want to filter properties camelCased and for some reason some properties are working, some does not.

This works and results into one document with given Id

```
var fBuilder = Builders<Document>.Filter;
fBuilder.Eq("Id", Guid.Parse("9e50b066-4320-4c30-9ce1-e939fb13836d")),
```

This does not.

```
var fBuilder = Builders<Document>.Filter;
fBuilder.Eq("id", Guid.Parse("9e50b066-4320-4c30-9ce1-e939fb13836d")),
```

This works, even though it should not in my opinion.

```
var fBuilder = Builders<Document>.Filter;
fBuilder.Eq("Filename", "document.json"),
```

Surprisingly this works too and this is what I want for all properties.

```
var fBuilder = Builders<Document>.Filter;
fBuilder.Eq("filename", "document.json"),
```

I think it has something to do with types of properties.

Currently I'm using MongoDB.Driver 2.9

Edit: When using SortDefinition for sorting, there is no such a problems and everything works fine